# How to show submitted webform data in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I created the webform and want to show the submitted webform data to the user.I am using webform.I want to show title,sender name and body.I used Webform Mysql Views module but I failed.Please help me

Answer (score 2):

```
function module-name_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
 // perform your task
 }

This function is called after you save any data in webform. this gives you the webform node id object and submission id. with this you can perform your all the task and show the data to the user.
```